# log jupyter notebook and get output and input number?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to write a tutorial for python (assume basic python) and  I want to make a pdf version using `latex`. I want to run a session of `jupyter notebook` and write codes step by step and print the steps in pdf.

I want to get something like this:

```
In [12]: a = 'foo'

In [13]: type(a)
Out[13]: str
```

When I use  magic code `%logstart -o myfile.py` I get something like this:

```
2+2
#[Out]# 4
```

is there anyway to log my codes like first style?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the notebook as a web page with File > Download as > HTML, will save the contents as they are presented on the screen.

You can then edit and convert that file to tex with the pandoc command-line utility:

```
pandoc -i notebook.html -o notebook.tex
```

After you're done editing the file (it's bound to have a few errors unfortunately), you can create a pdf:

```
pandoc -i notebook.tex -o notebook.pdf
```

Comment: yes it keeps markdown text and cell numbers as comments but I want output  and output cell number as comment.
your way does nothing about outputs.

Comment: You're quite right. Edited answer to highlight changes.